# Can't post data from Angular to my nodejs api

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-http

When I try to post data from angular to my nodejs backend it doesn't work.

[Backend] This is the function that catches the posted data. I tested it with postman and it worked. The console.log is just for testing. I have also a bodyParser running.

```
register : function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
}
```

[Frontend] This is the function that I call to send the data. I tested it with breakpoints and a console.log and the function is called. I think I tested all the possible ways to format the header.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    register(user:string): void{
         let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
         let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

         this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/register', { user }, options);

    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the `this.http.post(...);` I get this: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wecgU.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to post.

```
  this.http
       .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/register', { user }, options)
       .subscribe((result){

             console.log('result',result);

        });
```

To be more clear , Angualr2 http service is using rxjs Observables , and it's an observable in it's nature and observables are lazy , so unless you subscribe to them , they won't do anything.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you! I thought the problem was with the headers.